# Cannot transform XML to HTML through .NET System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:cf="http://AAA"
                xmlns="http://AAA"
                exclude-result-prefixes="cf">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/cf:Content">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>AAA</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Hello everybody
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="myxsl.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
<cf:Content xmlns:cf="http://AAA"
            xmlns="http://AAA">

  Hello.

</cf:Content>
```

The namespace referenced by the xml is an xsd of mine (validation is correct).

Well, is I open the xml file with a browser, the xslt works.

Now, I have this code:

```
string xml = "THE SAME XML OF THE XML FILE";

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
using (XmlReader xr = 
      XmlReader.Create("myxsl.xslt")) { 
   transform.Load(xr); 
}

try {
   using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
   using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
   using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)) {

      transform.Transform(xr, new XsltArgumentList(), sw);
      string html = sw.ToString();
      this.Preview_Literal.Text = html;

   }
} catch (Exception ex) {
throw ex;
}
```

Of course it get an exception:

> Error: Data at the root level is
>   invalid. Line 1, position 1. - Type:
>   System.Xml.XmlException

What is the problem?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `<?xml-stylesheet ...` line?

Comment: Which statement exactly gives you the exception?

Comment: Some comments: if you want your stylesheet to create HTML output then using `<xsl:output method="html" .../>` instead of method="xml" is the right approach. And if you want to create HTML elements then remove the `xmlns="http://AAA"` from the `xsl:stylesheet` as HTML elements don't belong in that namespace. None of that explains the error you get but I suspect that is not caused by XSLT at all, rather simply happening when the input markup is parsed as XML. Can you post a stack trace? Where/how is the `xml` variable populated?

Comment: @Martin: You are right, removing namespaces was the irght choice, now it works. Thankyou :) Make that your answer, I'll check it as this question answer :) Thanks again

Comment: @martin: perhaps you'd like to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer:

remove the default namespace, `xmlns="http://AAA"`, from the `xsl:stylesheet` as HTML elements don't belong in that namespace. For example, `<head>` is actually `<cf:head>` by default.

Comment: Question: if Martin has answered it already, then why did you answer it again?

Comment: @John, since I found the question in the "unanswered" section. Since it had an answer, and a good one, I figured it should be "answered". Nothing more.

Comment: Why not let Martin answer the question?

Comment: If you check the dates - Martin commented the answer in 2011. I found this question at 2012. I figured he is not coming back to answer it. John, I can assure you I placed an "answer" just for the protocol - to mark this question answered.